# Finding the volume of bounded region by surface

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have given:

$$ \overrightarrow F = 2z \hat i - x \hat j + y \hat k $$

and the surface region bounded by $x = 0$, $y = 0$, $x = 2$, $y = 4$, $z = x^2 $, $z=2$

To find:

$$ \iiint \overrightarrow F dV$$

Do I just need to simply substitute the given limits as the following?

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^4 \int_{x^2}^2 (2z \hat i - x \hat j + y \hat k) \space  dz \space dy \space  dx $$

I doubt that $x^2$ ought to be given some value before integration.

Comment: $$\int_0^2 \int_0^4 \int_{x^2}^2  \space  dz \space dy \space  dx $$ is the volume. What exactly do you have to compute? Is it not the surface integral of $\vec F$?

Comment: The volume integral, yes but is it correct what I am doing?

Comment: The limits are OK. $x^2$ is OK as the lower limit of the integration with respect to $z$.  But I still don't understand what kind of integral you aro to evaluate. $$\int_0^2 \int_0^4 \int_{x^2}^2 (2z \hat i - x \hat j + y \hat k) \space  dz \space dy \space  dx =\hat i2\int_0^2 \int_0^4 \int_{x^2}^2z\ dz \space \ dy \space  dx-\hat j\int_0^2 \int_0^4 \int_{x^2}^2x\ dz \space dy \space  dx+\hat k\int_0^2 \int_0^4 \int_{x^2}^2 y \ dz \space dy \space  dx.$$ I sort of don't believe that this is what you have to calculate.